# Angular + image upload. Having trouble getting form data to back end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I have been struggling to include a profile picture upload along with regular text data and send that all to the back end to create a new user through mongoose.  I have tried everything from ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload to building a custom directive but to not avail I still can't get the image or the data to make it to the server side.

My photo upload html snippet can be seen below:

```
  <div ng-show="!Login">
    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">Profile Picture</label>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <input type="file" file-input="files" multiple/>
      <button ng-click="upload()">Upload</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've created a custom directive "file-input" that looks like this:

```
app.directive('fileInput', ['$parse', function($parse){
  return {
  restrict: "A",
  link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
    elm.bind("change", function(){
      $parse(attrs.fileInput)
      .assign(scope, elm[0].files)
      scope.$apply()
    });
  }
} 
}])
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
  $scope.upload = function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', $scope.files[0])
    console.log(fd);
    userFactory.addPhoto(fd)
    .success(function(data){
      console.log("Data: ", data);
    })
  }
```

this is my service for the form data post to the backend:

```
   userFactory.addPhoto = function(fd){
    return $http.post('/users/addPhoto', fd, {
      transformRequest:angular.identity,
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': undefined
      }
    })
  }
```

So the problem with this is that when I send the data to the backend and it gets there I get a blank req.body object with nothing inside of it

```
router.post('/addPhoto', function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.body);
  // var profilePicture = new Buffer(req.file.buffer, 'base64').toString('ascii')
  // console.log(profilePicture);
});
```

What's happening here?  I'd like to get the image in a buffer in the backend so i can base64 encode it and store it in mongodb with mongoose.

If anyone has a way to send both the image and text data together by passing them into a ng-click function, getting them to the controller so I can put them both in an object, and then sending that object through to the backend together to register a new  user I would greatly prefer that solution.

Comment: This `router.post` is not the way, how you can get response from the backend. You can get the answer of the backend in `$http.post().success()` function.

Comment: i am using $http.post() in my service. I am returning that promise to the controller to handle the success().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need correct http headers. A `content-type = undefined` won't work. Instead it should be `Content-Type: multipart/form-data\n`. That being said, there are many angular upload directives, one of them being

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload.

which also supports older browsers. The following shows how to upload a file, e.g. an image, along with other data from a form using the above directive:

https://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/38/

Basically you give it a file and a url, and it creates a post request with the correct headers for a given image.

Comment: Hi @sboutzen - I use ng-file-upload, I have everything set-up, but when I click to upload - in my dev tools Network tab it's all peachy, the request payload is OK, status code is OK, but the file is not uploaded to server. This is my actual PHP that handles it:

`<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: multipart/form-data\n; charset=utf8');

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$dest = 'folder/' . $filename;
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , $dest );
 
?>`